# how to specify a pattern which contains only certain characters a certain number of times

Tags: regex, bash, grep, ls

I work with pseudonymized data where pseudonyms are strings 9 characters long containing either letters a through f or numbers 0 through 9.

How can I make `ls` show only entries with such names? Would this also work with `grep` and `find`?

I know that I can specify a single character as `[a-f,0-9]`, but how can I specify that such a character appears 9 times?

Comment: something like this? `[a-f,0-9]{9}`

Comment: Note that there are no comas to separate ranges in a class of characters, so `[a-f,0-9]` allows a `,` to pass, you should use `[a-f0-9]` instead

Comment: @NilsKähler How do I make it work? I tried to wrap it in single or double quotations, but it keeps telling no such file or directory.

Comment: @Renat : I don't see any actualy code in your question.

Comment: @user1934428 `[a-f,0-9]` would be the regex.

Comment: @Renat you should be able to do find with something like this if you are using GNU find with posix-extended `find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*/[a-f0-9]{9}'`. and grep with `grep -E '^[a-f0-9]{9}$'`

Comment: @NilsKähler Adding regextype made it work, an extension to the solution suggested by TheAlphaGhost below. And the `find` solution will do exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ls:

```
ls | grep -E '^[a-f0-9]{9}$'
```

find:

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -regex '.*/[a-f0-9]{9}$'
```

Comment: `find -maxdepth 1` to avoid searching in sub-directories.

Comment: Thank you, @TheAlphaGhost. This is close to what I want, even though ls plus grep would probably get some longer names which have the specified sequence in it, but happen to start and end with specified characters. The find solution though doesnt produce anything. The command without regex produces what is expected, but adding regex will remove all results.

Answer (score 2):

Alas, even with the `extglob` option there is no way to do what you want with only plain pattern matching in bash, except repeating 9 times `[a-f0-9]`:

```
r=[a-f0-9];ls $r$r$r$r$r$r$r$r$r
```

Or (3 characters less):

```
r=[a-f0-9];s=$r$r$r;ls $s$s$s
```

But you could also use a loop and the `=~` operator of conditional expressions:

```
for f in *; do [[ "$f" =~ ^[a-f0-9]{9}$ ]] && echo "$f"; done
```

If you have many non-matching files in the same directory then you can use the `extglob` option to limit the search to file names containing only the valid characters, and a simple test on the length:

```
( shopt -s extglob; for f in +([a-f0-9]); do (( "${#f}" == 9 )) && echo "$f"; done; )
```

(the sub-shell `( ... )` just to automatically restore the original `extglob` status afterwards)

With external utilities like `grep` and `find` the regular expression to use is the same as with `=~`: `^[a-f0-9]{9}$`.